# If $X$ is a Lévy process, is $\{t:\|X_t\|\ge c\}$ a *finite* stopping time?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a nontrivial $E$-valued càdlàg Lévy process and assume $c>0$ with $\|\Delta X_t\|_E\le c$ for all $t\ge0$. Let $$\tau:=\inf\{t\ge0:\|X_t\|_E\ge c\}.$$

Are we able to deduce that $\tau<\infty$; maybe at least almost surely?

Clearly, if $t\ge0$, then $\{\tau\ge t\}=\{\forall s\in[0,t):\|X_t\|_E<c\}$.

Comment: Wouldn't this follow from the fact that $\limsup_{t\to\infty}\|X_t\|=\infty$ a.s. for non-zero Lévy processes?

Comment: @nejimban I'm not aware of this fact. How do we prove it?

Comment: @0xbadf00d see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763761/asymptotic-behavior-of-l%C3%A9vy-processes).

Comment: (This is called Rogozin's theorem and there is a proof in Bertoin's book, Theorem VI.3.12.)

Comment: @nejimban You mean on p. 167?

Comment: Yes.$\vphantom{dummy}$

Comment: If it's non-zero, yes, otherwise, no.

Comment: @zhoraster I guess the extension of the real-valued to the normed vector space case is done by considering the Lévy processes $(\langle X_t,x'\rangle)_{t\ge0}$ for $x'\in E'$ and using that $\left\|x\right\|_E=\sup_{\|x'\|_{E'}\le1}\langle x,x'\rangle$, right?

Comment: @nejimban In the question you've linked, is it a typo in (iii)? As stated (ii) and (iii) seem to be the same. Shouldn't (iii) be $$\limsup_{t\to\infty}X_t=\color{red}+\infty\text{ a.s. and }\liminf_{t\to\infty}X_t=-\infty\text{ a.s.}$$ instead?

Comment: @0xbadf00d yes, there seems to be an unfortunate typo there. But the answer looks fine.

Comment: @nejimban Yes, thanks for clarifying. What do you think about the extension to the normed vector space case for this question?

Comment: I think it should extend fine as you said.

Comment: @nejimban I think there might be a problem with the nontriviality requirement: $\langle X,x'\rangle$ is clearly a Lévy process for all $x'\in E'$. But even when $X_t\ne0$ for some $t>0$ and $x'\ne0$, it could still hold that $\langle X_t,x'\rangle=0$, doesn't it?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Correct. But you just need non-triviality along *one* coordinate $x'$, right?

Comment: @nejimban On the other hand, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, if $X_t(\omega)\ne0$ for some $(\omega,t)$, then there is a $x'\in E'$ with $\langle X_t(\omega),x'\rangle=\|X_t(\omega)\|$. But that's not enough for the conclusion we're seeking for ...

Comment: @nejimban Why would *one* coordinate be sufficient? We've got $\left\|X_t\right\|_E=\sup_{\|x'\|_{E'}\le1}\langle X_t,x'\rangle$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130573/discussion-between-nejimban-and-0xbadf00d).