# If $X\sim Y$, how do we show $\limsup_{t\to\infty}X_t\sim\limsup_{t\to\infty}Y_t$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ be real-valued right-continuous processes on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $X\sim Y$ and \begin{align}M&:=\limsup_{t\to\infty}X_t;\\N&:=\limsup_{t\to\infty}Y_t.\end{align}

> How can we show that $M\sim N$?

Intuitively, the claim seems to be trivial, but how do we need to argue rigorously?

Maybe (if so, which argument do we need?) it is sufficient to consider a fixed $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$ and show that for \begin{align}\tilde M&:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_{t_n};\\\tilde N&:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}Y_{t_n}\end{align} it holds $\tilde M\sim\tilde N$.

Now, since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$ is generated by $\{[-\infty,a):a\in\mathbb Q\}$ or $\{(b,\infty],b\in\mathbb Q\}$, it is enough to determine the distributions on such sets.

Now I'm lacking a suitable characterization of when the limit superior has a fixed lower bound. If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\overline{\mathbb R}$, \begin{align}\tau&:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n;\\\sigma&:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n.\end{align} and $a,b\in\overline{\mathbb R}$. We can easily show that

1. If $\tau>a$, then $\forall n\in\mathbb N:x_n>a$.
2. $\tau\ge a$ iff $\forall n\in\mathbb N:x_n\ge a$.
3. $\tau<b$ iff $\exists n_0\in\mathbb N:x_{n_0}<b$.
4. $\sigma>a$ iff $\exists n_0\in\mathbb N:x_{n_0}>a$.
5. If $\sigma<b$, then $\forall n\in\mathbb N:x_n<b$.
6. $\sigma\le b$ iff $\forall n\in\mathbb N:x_n\le b$.

However, for $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ we can only show one direction. For example, letting \begin{align}\tilde\tau&:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\overbrace{\sup_{m\ge n}x_m}^{=:\:\sigma_n};\\\tilde\sigma&:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\underbrace{\inf_{m\ge n}x_m}_{=:\:\tau_n},\end{align} we have

7. If $\tilde\tau<b$, then $\exists n_0\in\mathbb N:\forall n\in\mathbb N_0:x_n<b$.
8. If $\exists n_0\in\mathbb N:\forall n\in\mathbb N_0:x_n\le b$, then $\tilde\tau\le b$.

Comment: What does $X \sim Y$ mean?

Comment: I don't believe this is true unless you have additional assumptions e.g., that the sample paths are a.s continuous

Comment: @Mason It means that the distributions of $X$ and $Y$, considered as $\mathbb R^{[0,\:\infty)}$-random variables, are equal.

Comment: @AlohaSine I'm willing to assume right-continuity.